Input Overlay sprite and config generator
The OBS Studio software used for video streaming and recording may be extended with additional functionality. In my case, I have extended it with the Input Overlay plugin that allows me add an Input Overlay layer that shows keystrokes while playing a game, in which case it required you to enter:

The RGBA bitmap image containing the keys in default and pressed states.
The configuration file (actually a JSON) defining how to map key codes to slices in the RGBA bitmap image, among few other details.

There exist presets shared by various authors, however I would like to be able to create new Input Overlay projects using different keyboard layouts.
I am looking for a software that does the following:

generates a very minimalistic RGBA bitmap image according to specified layout;
generates a JSON configuration file according to the RGBA bitmap.

If it is paid, it may cost at most $3,4.
The helper software must be available in any desktop operating system.

This is a "tilting at windmills" kind of request. The likelihood of such software ever exisiting, whether free or paid, is extremely low.
Why?

the format isn't universal, it's Input Overlay specific
the plugin isn't too popular, relatively
creating layouts manually is not the hardest and most timetaking task
a similar tool is already provided by the author - io-cct. It's not nearly as simple as you'd like, since it requires input of a texture/sprite file that you need to process, but at least it makes the JSON part faster. Here's the tutorial for it.

